# Effectively use query results using web.py

Tags: mysql, web.py

I am using web.py for managing my web application and using MySQL as the database. I make a raw query and get the results and i convert it to a list and iterate over it. I need to push the retrieved columns in Arrays (or Numpy arrays) and then plot using Matplotlib. Everything works but i am not sure if the approach i use is most efficient?
The code is:

```
retrieved_data=list(db.query(query))
LEN=len(retrieved_data)
x=[0]*LEN
y=[0]*LEN
X=[None]*LEN
for i in range(0,LEN):
    x[i]=retrieved_data[i]["timestamp"]
    y[i]=retrieved_data[i][parameter]
    X[i]=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x[i],pytz.timezone(TIMEZONE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to convert the result of db.query if you only need to iterate it once. So your particular example can be a little bit simplified.

```
x, y, X = [], [], []
for item in db.query(query):
    x.append(item.timestamp)
    y.append(item[parameter])
    X.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item.timestamp,
                                             pytz.timezone(TIMEZONE))
```

Or if you need to iterate many times on the same result, you may use `.list()` method to convert it into list.

```
retrieved_data = db.query(query).list()
```

Comment: Won't append be slower than simple indexing, since due to append the size of list will vary with each iteration. The tradeoff will be then: Convert to list vs Append at each iteration (no conversion needed)

Comment: Not sure about performance, but I think calling list on db query result will need to iterate over it 1 more time under the hood.